# Python Polynomial Domain has wrong number of elements

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I started working with polynomials in Python and I defined a simple one as you will see in the code bellow. The problem is that it gives me an error message saying:

> ValueError: Domain has wrong number of elements.

I am using the numpy module and the numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial class

Here is the code:

```
p1 = numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial(1, 2, 3)
print(p1)
```

As I understand the arguments correspond for the coefficients in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient needs to be *array_like*, so you need to wrap it as a tuple or list:

```
np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial((1,2,3))
# Polynomial([ 1.,  2.,  3.], [-1,  1], [-1,  1])
```

Or:

```
np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial([1,2,3])
```